# Take last element from std::views::split at constexpr

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, std-ranges

Is there a better way to take the last element from the result of a std::views::split in a constexpr context?

This is the best I could come up with given how restrictive the interface is for the split view. Its not great since there should really be no need to iterate everything.

```
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

constexpr std::string_view lastdot(std::string_view input) {
    std::string_view delim{"."};
    std::string_view out;
    
    auto words = std::views::split(input, delim);

    std::size_t numwords = 0;

    std::ranges::for_each(words, [&](const auto word){
        numwords++;
    });

    std::size_t counter = 1;
    std::ranges::for_each(words, [&](auto word){
        if(counter == numwords)
            out = std::string_view{word.begin(), word.end()};
        counter++;
    });

    return out;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto out = lastdot("abc.def.ghi.jkl");
    std::cout << out << '\n';
}
```

[Godbolted](https://godbolt.org/z/E3s8aMbT8)

Comment: std::views::split might not be the best tool if you only want the last element. Try something like the following: input.substr(input.rfind(".")+1);

Comment: @qianfg That is a great solution, you should leave it as an answer. Ranges were a bit overkill for this situation. new: https://godbolt.org/z/7q7b9r3d3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::views::split might not be the best tool if you only want the last element. Try something like the following:

```
constexpr std::string_view lastdot(std::string_view input) {
  auto pos = input.rfind(".");
  return input.substr(pos == input.npos ? 0 : (pos + 1));
}
```